# How do I set dns address from an android application

Tags: android, dns, settings, vpn

I want to develop an android program that can change DNS adress.

I found something but that was about changing WIFI's DNS ADRESS. It could be change all the DNS adress.

I need your suggestions. Thanks in advance.